# YAML.load(file) returning false?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have a file object which points to an empty `.yml` file. When I try to load this file with `YAML.load` I get `false` instead of an empty hash. Is this the expected behavior?

`file.read` is returning `""` as expected.

Answer (score 6):

That's probably because `YAML.parse("")` returns `false`. So I suppose this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify `load_file` function as below:

Instead of

`data_hash = YAML.load_file(yaml_file)`

To

`data_hash = YAML.load_file(yaml_file, {})`

So when empty `YAML` file is provided to the `load_file` function, it will return an empty hash (my Ruby version is Ruby 2.4.0p0)

Example:
empty file : /Users/batman/config/config.yml

```
 irb:
    2.4.0 :001 > require 'yaml'
    => true 
    2.4.0 :006 > YAML.load_file("/Users/batman/config/config.yml",{})
    => {}
```